# Why do searches redirect to “SuddenLink.net”, instead of my default browser search engine? Can I prevent this?

Tags: browser, redirection, isp

I’m using Chrome, and I’ve set my search engine to Bing. This works the way I expect 99 times out of 100, but occasionally my searches go to `search.SuddenLink.net` instead. Apparently, it’s legit URL. There's even a “Why am I here?” and “Disable this Service” links on that page; see picture below. But this continues to happen, even after using these settings to "Disable this Service."

1. Where does this change happen (browser, ISP, somewhere else?)
2. How can I prevent this behavior? I’d really like to block all attempts to redirect me to that search URL.
3. Would it possible to create problems by blocking my ISP’s URLs?

[image: A screenshot of SuddenLink’s page.]

Comment: Are you using your ISPs DNS servers? They might be adding their IP addresses to capture users.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Suddenlink's DNS. Unfortunately, it looks like they're clearly the fastest. Is there any way to prevent this redirect, without using a different DNS?

Comment: "You nay disable it by clicking here" ... click there. ;p

Comment: "But those setting doesn’t seem to be reliable" ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your Domain Name System (DNS) request, the ISP may capture it and transfer you to a "helpful" page.

It's becoming quite common for ISPs to start offering search pages for increased revenue.

What happens is that your browser goes to your Operating System for DNS information in a cache. From there, if the domain name is not in the cache, it will retrieve it from the router/modem. If the information is not cached there, a search on a DNS server will have to be preformed. Most ISPs host DNS servers to allow their clients to look up information.

Most routers/modems pass DNS server information via DHCP, a way of dynamically allocating local network IP addresses.

To change this behaviour:

- Click on the "Why am I here" or "disable this" links and follow the steps.
- Wait 24 hours. Some ISPs only update their settings at midnight/after peak hours.
- Try flushing DNS cache information from your browser, OS, and router/modem.
- Contact your ISP if the page still displays, automatic removal might have failed.
- Use another Name Server, such as Google's pair: 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4

Comment: Great information, thanks! So, when using a browser that has an "omni-bar" type situation, why do some bad addresses turn into searches, but others get redirected to a DNS lookup? Is that something the browser decides? I.e. "This looks more like an address than it does a search request... I'll send it on to the DNS."

Comment: @mHurley The browser itself makes a guess on what the user intended to do. For instance, Firefox makes an assumption that anything followed by a dot and two or three characters is a domain name. The address bar in a browser is no longer an address bar, but a general query.

Answer (score 0):

Always use HTTPS when going to your search engine. HTTPS can't be redirected to an impostor.

Comment: Unless they are spoofing DNS/send back manipulated DNS answers. Then only key pinning can prevent redirections.

Comment: @GiantTree DNS spoofing can't get his browser to trust a bogus cert, unless they've already compromised his system to trust a bad root CA. In which case he has bigger problems than redirected searches. Key pinning is a defense against accidentally trusting untrustworthy root CA's (such as ones that intentionally or accidentally issue bogus certs). I doubt that's what he's up against here.